# Tailwind CSS classes not rendering on Nginx server but working on Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, tailwind-css, gunicorn, nginx-config

I am facing an issue with my Django web application where the Tailwind CSS classes are not rendering when accessing the site through the Nginx server. Strangely, the Tailwind CSS classes are applied correctly when running the application using Gunicorn.

I have carefully checked my static file configuration and confirmed that Nginx is properly serving other static files, such as images and JavaScript files. However, the Tailwind CSS classes seem to be the only ones not functioning as expected.

Here is my current Nginx server block configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /Users/curtwheeler/Documents/Django/Business/cookiecutters/base/base/var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /Users/curtwheeler/Documents/Django/Business/cookiecutters/base/base/var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static {
        root /Users/curtrosenblad/Documents/Django/Business/cookiecutters/base/base/base;
    }

    location /media {
        root /Users/curtrosenblad/Documents/Django/Business/cookiecutters/base/base/base;
    }
}
```

I have already checked the file permissions and ownership of the static files, and they appear to be set correctly. Additionally, during the collectstatic process, the Tailwind CSS files are being correctly copied to the static files directory.

I suspect that there might be a misconfiguration or missing directive in my Nginx server block that is causing the issue. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly configure Nginx to ensure that the Tailwind CSS classes are rendered correctly when accessing the application through the Nginx server.